# entity framework indexes are generated wrongly

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I am trying to create 2 indexes like this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<MyEntity>()
    .HasIndex(p => new { p.Column1, p.Column2, p.Column3, p.Column4 })
    .HasName("ix_index1")
    .IsUnique();

modelBuilder.Entity<MyEntity>()
    .HasIndex(p => new { p.Column1, p.Column2, p.Column3 })
    .HasName("ix_index2")
    .IsUnique();
```

Upon running command `add-migration InitialCreate` what I get in return, is this script:

```
CreateTable(
    "DEV.MyEntity",
    c => new
        {
            Column1 = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 10),
            Column2 = c.Decimal(nullable: false, precision: 19, scale: 0),
            Column3 = c.Decimal(nullable: false, precision: 10, scale: 0),
            Column4 = c.Decimal(nullable: false, precision: 10, scale: 0),
        })
    .PrimaryKey(t => new { t.Column1, t.Column2, t.Column3 })
    .Index(t => new { t.Column1, t.Column2, t.Column3 }, unique: true, name: "ix_index2")
    .Index(t => t.Column4, unique: true, name: "ix_index1");
```

Is there a reason why of all columns in index `ix_index1` only `Column4` is present? The expected result is that `ix_index1` is for 4 columns.

If that's relevant, I am using managed Oracle Database provider. Entity framework version 6.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, since the approach I have tried originally is confirmed to be broken due to bug - I was able to find another solution, which seems to be working OK, but is much more dirty.

For example, imagine that you want to create 4 indexes as following:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<MyEntity2>()
    .HasIndex(p => new { p.Column1, p.Column2, p.Column3, p.Column5 })
    .HasName("ix_1")
    .IsUnique();

modelBuilder.Entity<MyEntity2>()
    .HasIndex(p => new { p.Column1, p.Column2, p.Column4, p.Column5 })
    .HasName("ix_2")
    .IsUnique();

modelBuilder.Entity<MyEntity2>()
    .HasIndex(p => new { p.Column1, p.Column2, p.Column3 })
    .HasName("ix_3")
    .IsUnique();

modelBuilder.Entity<MyEntity2>()
    .HasIndex(p => new { p.Column1, p.Column2, p.Column4 })
    .HasName("ix_4")
    .IsUnique();
```

**The result (as of the moment of writing 31.07.2018) will be broken.**

To correctly create all indexes, you have to use following approach instead:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<MyEntity2>()
    .Property(e => e.Column1)
    .HasColumnAnnotation(
        IndexAnnotation.AnnotationName,
        new IndexAnnotation(new[]
        {
            new IndexAttribute("ix_3", 1) { IsUnique = true },
            new IndexAttribute("ix_4", 1) { IsUnique = true },
            new IndexAttribute("ix_2", 1) { IsUnique = true },
            new IndexAttribute("ix_1", 1) { IsUnique = true }
        }));

modelBuilder.Entity<MyEntity2>()
    .Property(e => e.Column2)
    .HasColumnAnnotation(
        IndexAnnotation.AnnotationName,
        new IndexAnnotation(new[]
        {
            new IndexAttribute("ix_3", 2) { IsUnique = true },
            new IndexAttribute("ix_4", 2) { IsUnique = true },
            new IndexAttribute("ix_2", 2) { IsUnique = true },
            new IndexAttribute("ix_1", 2) { IsUnique = true }
        }));

modelBuilder.Entity<MyEntity2>()
    .Property(e => e.Column3)
    .HasColumnAnnotation(
        IndexAnnotation.AnnotationName,
        new IndexAnnotation(new[]
        {
            new IndexAttribute("ix_3", 3) { IsUnique = true },
            new IndexAttribute("ix_1", 3) { IsUnique = true }
        }));

modelBuilder.Entity<MyEntity2>()
    .Property(e => e.Column4)
    .HasColumnAnnotation(
        IndexAnnotation.AnnotationName,
        new IndexAnnotation(new[]
        {
            new IndexAttribute("ix_4", 3) { IsUnique = true },
            new IndexAttribute("ix_2", 3) { IsUnique = true },
        }));

modelBuilder.Entity<MyEntity2>()
    .Property(e => e.Column5)
    .HasColumnAnnotation(
        IndexAnnotation.AnnotationName,
        new IndexAnnotation(new[]
        {
            new IndexAttribute("ix_2", 4) { IsUnique = true },
            new IndexAttribute("ix_1", 4) { IsUnique = true },
        }));
```

I hope I have not messed up any numbers. But the idea should be understandable.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like EF6 bug (I guess in attempt to optimize redundant indexes). The database provider is irrelevant (the same happens with SqlServer provider).

One of the wrong behaviors is the one you've described. Another is if you exchange the order of the two `HasIndex` calls, the generated migration contains a correct `ix_index1`, but `ix_index2` is missing at all.

Since it's a bug, there is not much that can be don other than reporting the issue to EF6 issue tracker and wait to eventually get it fixed.

However, if `(Column1, Column2, Column2)` is a PK as indicated by the migration, then the `ix_index2` is redundant and you can safely remove it from the fluent configuration, which will allow correctly generating the `ix_index1`.

Comment: About - `is redundant and you can safely remove it `. In this particular case - I just wanted to give index a name :) P.s. I was able to resolve the issue seconds ago, using `IndexAnnotation` approach, which I will post soon. It is, however, is not as pretty and readable as my original approach, but it gets the job done. I will create a bug report, as you have suggested! Thank you